# Testing the results from an IActionResult controller method, when the return is a Tuple value

Tags: c#, tuples

I've got a controller method that returns this to the client

```
return Ok(new { user, profile});
```

It used to return the user object on its own, so my unit test on the method looked like this

```
var res = await _controller.Get(_userId);
var okResult = res as OkObjectResult;
var resUser = okResult.Value as User;
```

i could then test individule bits of my return

```
Assert.Contains("user@domain.com", resUser.EmailAddress);
```

However, now i'm returning a a tuple object our of the controller method its not working. Ive tried doing

```
var resUser1 = okResult.Value as Tuple<User, Profile>;
```

But that always returns me null. Any idea how i can convert my result from the controller into something i can look into now its not just a flat object?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use `ValueTuple` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting a ValueTuple from a cached object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940210/casting-a-valuetuple-from-a-cached-object)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i tried to use the ValueTuple to cast the result but it still seamed to bring back a null object, so i ended up just creating a real object for the result and casting to that object worked fine